# How to import images in to SQLite and retrieve in separate activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to save images to an SQLite database on my android application. I wish to save these images and then be able to retrieve and display them in a separate activity. I have the database functioning fine with all the strings needed by am struggling to work out how to import, save and retrieve images from the DB. Preferably a user would be able to select these images from their gallery (using a gallery intent perhaps?) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### CODE IN DATABASE HELPER

```
public class DBHelperTrips extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//declaring the structure of the SQLite database
private static final int DATADASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tripinformation.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tripinformation";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "Id";
private static final String COLUMN_TRIPNAME = "tripName";
private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String COLUMN_TRIPBEGIN = "tripBegin";
private static final String COLUMN_TRIPEND = "tripEnd";
private static final String COLUMN_EXTRA = "extra";
private static final String TAG = "";
//tag needs input?

//naming the database
SQLiteDatabase dbtripinformation;

//creating the table
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table tripinformation(Id integer primary key not null ," +
        "tripName text not null , location text not null , tripBegin text not null , tripEnd text not null, extra text);";


public DBHelperTrips(Context context)
{
    super(context , DATABASE_NAME, null , DATADASE_VERSION);
}


//on create method
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.dbtripinformation = db;

}

//inserting user information method
//this is called when a new user is registered
public void insertTripInformation(TripInformation user)
{
    dbtripinformation = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

    //getting content of db that is already present by querying with cursor information

    String query = "select * from tripinformation";
    Cursor cursor = dbtripinformation.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();


    //this places the inputs in to the various columns in the SQlite db
    value.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
    value.put(COLUMN_TRIPNAME, user.getTripName());
    value.put(COLUMN_LOCATION, user.getLocation());
    value.put(COLUMN_TRIPBEGIN, user.getTripBegin());
    value.put(COLUMN_TRIPEND, user.getTripEnd());
    value.put(COLUMN_EXTRA, user.getExtra());


    //insert table
    dbtripinformation.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, value);
    //closing the database
    dbtripinformation.close();
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    String queryDrop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(queryDrop);
    this.onCreate(dbtripinformation);

}

public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;

}
```

### CREATE INSTANCE OF TRIP ACTIVITY

```
public class createTrip extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelperTrips helper = new DBHelperTrips(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_trip);

    final Button buttonReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReturn);
    buttonReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            returnToMain();
        }
    });

    final Button makeTrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makeYourTrip);
    makeTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createTrip();
        }
    });
}

public void returnToMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mainTripPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}

public void createTrip() {
    //THIS NEEDS TO CREATE A FILE TO STORE THE INFORMATION TO USING A DATABASE CONNECTION AND THEN DISPLAY A TOAST SHOWING THAT THE
    //TRIP HAS BEEN CREATED, AFTER THAT THE TEXTBOXES SHOULD CLEAR AND THE USER SHOULD BE ABLE TO RETURN TO MAIN MENU


    //creates an instance of each edittext on the screen
    EditText tripName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTextTitle);
    EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTextTripLocation);
    EditText startDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDateStart);
    EditText endDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDateEnd);
    EditText extra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTextExtra);

    //assigns string values to each input from the user
    String tripTitle = tripName.getText().toString();
    String locationOfTrip = location.getText().toString();
    String dateStart = startDate.getText().toString();
    String dateEnd = endDate.getText().toString();
    String extraInfo = extra.getText().toString();

    TripInformation user = new TripInformation();

    user.setExtra(extraInfo);
    user.setLocation(locationOfTrip);
    user.setTripBegin(dateStart);
    user.setTripEnd(dateEnd);
    user.setTripName(tripTitle);

    helper.insertTripInformation(user);

    Toast created = Toast.makeText(createTrip.this, "New Trip Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    TextView v = (TextView) created.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    created.show();

    tripName.setText("");
    location.setText("");
    startDate.setText("");
    endDate.setText("");
    extra.setText("");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As my personal experience saving images in SQLite is not good practice, it will increase app storage memory.

So its good practice to store images in device local(internal/external) memory then save respected image path in SQLite db for your reference.

When it comes to usage fetch that saved image path in SQLite then load image from local storage memory with that path and display it on the screen.

Hope this process helpful.

@Rajesh